# How to use magento wordpress subdomain with fishpig

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I have wordpress integrated Fishpig environment in Magento working fine as

> domain.com/blog

But I need to use it as

> blog.domain.com

how can i setup "Home URL" in magento Fishpig settings for this?

I already changed wordpress siteurl to be blog.domain.com

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

there is a way.
at integration path, I set `../wp/` and fishpig connect successfull.

at my case my default server path is:

```
/home/servename/public_html/
```

using `../` I return to `/home/servename/`
and wp is my subdirectory folder.
full path is:

```
/home/servename/wp/
```

If you migrated your wordpress you will need replace all server patch

Changing the absolute paths of the website URL ('siteurl') and URL of the home (homeurl '):

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value,
'http://www.siteantigo.com.br', 'http://www.sitenovo.com.br')
WHERE option_name = 'home'
OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

change GUID:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET guid = REPLACE (guid,
'http://www.siteantigo.com.br', 'http://www.sitenovo.com.br');
```

Change URLs within content

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,
'http://www.siteantigo.com.br', 'http://www.sitenovo.com.br');
```

Ghange image paths:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,
'src="http://www.siteantigo.com.br', 'src="http://www.siteantigo.com.br');
```

attachments GUID

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET guid = REPLACE (guid,
'http://www.siteantigo.com.br', 'http://www.siteantigo.com.br')
WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

works for me.
I hope it helped...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the extension for technical reasons. Magento needs to be able to intercept the request and for this to happen, WordPress needs to be in a sub-directory of Magento.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I am doing some work around within the extension to get this done.